# Error running WSGI application django Error on pythonanywhere

Tags: django, wsgi, pythonanywhere, django-wsgi

I'm bit in hurry but stuck on this problem for a long time.
I don't know what should I do. My error throws an error about WSGI.
When I saw Error Log,

```html
2019-12-16 08:53:45,120: Error running WSGI application
2019-12-16 08:53:45,121:   File "/var/www/000_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 3
 
2019-12-16 08:53:45,122: SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

2019-12-16 08:54:12,944: Error running WSGI application
2019-12-16 08:54:12,946:   File "/var/www/000_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 3

2019-12-16 08:54:12,947: SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
2
2019-12-16 08:54:14,487: Error running WSGI application
2019-12-16 08:54:14,487:   File "/var/www/000_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 3
2
2019-12-16 10:40:06,493:     ^
2019-12-16 10:40:06,493:
```

This is what I saw.

/var/www/000_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py     also includes

```html
  
   
import os
import sys

path = 'home/000/koo'
if path not in sys.path:
sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: what is ^ pointing at in your traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have this:

```
if path not in sys.path:
sys.path.append(path)
```

That's not valid Python; you need to indent the code that is run if the condition in the `if` statement is True, like this:

```
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I already solved this problem in different in other way, but I'll try this later! Thanks a lot!